# Modal loads before content is displayed

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am rendering a bootstrap modal with the content received from a REST call, but the modal gets rendered before the content could populate.

The modal load event is on a button click, and if i click that button again after some seconds, then the modal shows with the populated content.

How to delay the modal rendering, until the content from the REST call arrives?

Modal:

```
<!--- Get Fields --->

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" >
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Configure Fields</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-6">                 
             <div class="checkbox">
                <label> <strong>Show Fields</strong>&nbsp;</label>
               <input type="checkbox" id="select_all" ng-click="multiSelectCheckBox()">
               <label for="select_all">Select All</label>
             </div>    
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-6">

           </div>
           <hr/> 
           <div class="col-md-12">
              <ul class="columns_3 list-unstyled" data-columns="3">
                        <li ng-repeat="(key,field) in fields">
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="jirafield{{$index}}" name="{{key}}"
                                    ng-checked="field.required || selectallcheckboxes || inselectedfields(field)"
                                    ng-disabled="field.required"
                                    ng-model="field.isActive"
                                    ng-click="checkBoxSelect(key,field)"> <label
                                    for="jirafield{{$index}}">{{field.name}}</label>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
           </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="savefields()">Save</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-cancel" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="clearselectedfields()">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

REST Call:

```
var getfieldsfromJIRA = function(projectkey, domain, authenticatedToken){
                    return $.ajax
                    ({
                          type: "GET",
                          url: ipAddress+":8089/issue/get?projectKeys="+projectkey+"&domainName=http://"+domain,
                          async: false,
                          headers: {
                            "Authorization": authenticatedToken
                          },
                          success: function (res){
                            console.log(res);

                          }
                        });
                }
```

JS Service call:

```
$scope.getfieldsfromJIRA = function(projectkey, domain, auth, username, password){
                //if(!$scope.fieldssaved){
                    var authenticatedToken = auth +" "+ window.btoa(username+":"+password);
                    projectsettingsfactory.getfieldsfromJIRA(projectkey, domain, authenticatedToken).then(function successCallBack(response){
                        angular.forEach(response.data.projects, function(project){
                            angular.forEach(project.issuetypes, function(issuetype){
                                angular.forEach(issuetype.fields, function(field, key){
                                    $scope.fields[key] = field;
                                    if(field.required){
                                        $scope.requiredfields[key] = field;
                                        $scope.selectedfields[key] = field;
                                    }
                                });
                            });
                        });

                        if(Object.keys($scope.fields).length === Object.keys($scope.selectedfields).length){
                            $scope.selectallcheckboxes = true;
                        }
                    }, function errorCallBack(response){
                        alerts.error("Error in finding fields");
                    });
}
```

Comment: can you share code?

Answer (score 0):

Write the modal open call in the success function of the REST API call. On click you can make the API call, That way, the modal will surely have the requested data

Answer (score 0):

```js
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#myModal').modal();
}, 3000);
```

Comment: $(...).modal is not a function. This error appears.

Comment: <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>   use it or change  $  to jQuery  so it will   jQuery  ('#myModal').modal();

Comment: Waiting 3 seconds is actually pretty bad practice. In slow network or for heavy operations the rest call might actually take longer, and on a fast network 3 seconds seem to be arbitrary long.